# transaction upload file and add to database in php

Tags: php, try-catch

Hello I want to upload file and add it to database.
Also if one fails i want to reverse entire process.
Is it good way to do this ? Or should I change it ?

```
    try {
    if($filesystem->copy($originFile, $targetFile))
        if(!$db->adddd)$filesystem->remove($targetFile);

} catch (IOExceptionInterface $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what `filesystem` is or does.

Comment: it's a part from symfony 2 I install via composser...